# Remove index.php from URL (CodeIgniter)

Tags: forms, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I've removed the index.php throught this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /leet/index.php/$1 [L]
```

But when I submit form `<?=form_open('signup');?>` and the page refreshes the url changes its value to `localhost/ci/index.php/signup`.

Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: I answered with another thing in mind, so it was a mistaken answer...to be deleted.

Comment: I've removed `index.php` successfully, but *only* when a form is submitted in the url is inserted `index.php`. (хехе, от България си ^_^)

Comment: you should also remove index.php references from the config.php file - base_url and index_page, I don't remember exactly which was, but I think the form_helpers use these values to construct urls. (да :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must check your config.php inside your application\config directory, as you can see, locate your

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Change that to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
<?= form_open_multipart(base_url().'/controller_name/function_name') ?>
```

I hope it helps you.