# Codeigniter Form Open How To Remove index.php

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

In Codeigniter when I use `form_open()` function it adds `index.php` to url.
How can remove it ?
Note : I removed index.php from url with htaccess.

Comment: Do it globally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653589/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can give action to the form_open(),something like this

```
form_open(base_url().'your_controller_name/function_name');
```

Comment: ```form_open(base_url('your_controller_name', 'function_name'));```would be actually more appropriate

Answer (score 4):

You not removed the index.php from $config['index_page'] = "index.php";

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
//$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: This answer should have been accepted instead of the other. The other requires to add a base_url() all the time, while removing the index.php from the var index_page inside the config file is the solutions that's been advices if your using mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Open App.php

and find and change: `public $indexPage = '';`